# Is using an instance of a class to access static methods considered bad practice?

Tags: php, oop

Is using an instance of a class to access static methods considered bad practice?

I.e.

```
$model = new MyClass();
$options = MyClass::getOptions();
```

vs

```
$model = new MyClass();
$options = $model::getOptions();
```

(`$model` is instantiated in either case, I'm just wondering if one approach is preferable to the other.)

Comment: @SiGanteng the IDE doesn't complain, and it runs...

Comment: ok then, my fault, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traditionally the first way (specifying the class name itself) has more similarities with other languages such as Java.

The second one is unique to PHP (afaik); it works because the `::` operator disambiguates the expression, unlike Java where a period is used for both instance and static properties.

I'm not sure what the performance impact is by using the second option, but I think it comes down to personal taste / coding standards.

**Conclusion**

If the types of your instances are immediately clear from the surrounding code it might be easier to go for the second option (sometimes the class name can be pretty big); but if not, use the first option as it's the most explicit.

Answer (score 3):

That depends, I think. You can happily use static methods for many happy years, enjoying instantiation-free code, but one day you'll have to reroute *some* (that's where it goes) calls to another, descendant class, so simple search-and-replace call won't do. ) So going with a prepared object is a safer route, I think.

As an alternative, you can use something like this:

```
$className = 'MyClass';
$className::classyMethod1();
$className::classyMethod2();
```

... but that may become pretty confusing with time, I suppose (and is usable only in PHP 5.3+)

Answer (score 1):

I believe, this alternative:

```
$options = MyClass::getOptions();
```

actually is wasting less memory, because you aren't needing a extra variable to call the static function.